# Plotly pie graph not showing all data

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I have noticed that my go.Pie graph only shows 2 of the 3 values held in the dataframe column. I noticed this when creating a px.treemap referencing the exact same column in the dataframe and it shows all 3 values.

Below is my code for the pie chart and then the treemap

```
#docCategory count pie graph
valuesDocCat = df['docCategory'].value_counts()
figDocCat = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels = df['docCategory'], values = valuesDocCat)])
figDocCat.update_traces(textposition = 'inside')
figDocCat.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=14, uniformtext_mode='hide', title='Document Category breakdown')

#treeMap test graph
valuesTreemap = df['Kind'].value_counts()
figTreemap = px.treemap(df, path = ['docCategory', 'Kind'], color='docCategory')
figTreemap.update_traces(root_color='lightgrey')
figTreemap.update_layout(margin = dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25)
```

You can see my code above referencing the `df['docCategory']` in both instances but as you can see in the images below the pie chart doesnt have the 'Unknown' field whereas the treemap does.

Any ideas on why? I have other pie charts that have more than 2 fields being referenced and no issues, it is just happening on this one.

[image: piechart]

[image: treemap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your question **"Plotly pie graph not showing all data"**, it is showing everything.
- `figDocCat = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels = df['docCategory'], values = valuesDocCat)])`

  - you are passing different length arrays for `labels` and `values`.  **plotly** is taking first 3 items from labels, some of which are the same.
  - to be consistent this line would be `figDocCat = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=valuesDocCat.index, values=valuesDocCat)])`.  i.e. both labels and values come from the same **pandas** series
- have simulated data frame to demonstrate

#### full solution

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cats = {
    "Structured": ["Spreadsheet"],
    "Unknown": ["System File", "Unrecognised"],
    "Unstrcutured": ["Document", "Email", "Image", "Calendar Entry"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"docCategory": c, "Kind": np.random.choice(cats[c], 2)[0]}
        for c in np.random.choice(list(cats.keys()), 25)
    ]
)
# docCategory count pie graph
valuesDocCat = df["docCategory"].value_counts()
figDocCat = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=valuesDocCat.index, values=valuesDocCat)])
figDocCat.update_traces(textposition="inside")
figDocCat.update_layout(
    uniformtext_minsize=14, uniformtext_mode="hide", title="Document Category breakdown"
)
figDocCat.show()

# treeMap test graph
valuesTreemap = df["Kind"].value_counts()
figTreemap = px.treemap(df, path=["docCategory", "Kind"], color="docCategory")
figTreemap.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
figTreemap.update_layout(margin=dict(t=50, l=25, r=25, b=25))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Rob that has worked a treat. I guess it was just my lack of understanding on the prefixs I could use. The .index is a good one to know and that might clean up some other parts of my code for other things :) again thankyou for providing such a detailed reply.